# Filter json data in controller, the right way

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

(there are other questions but neither helped me out)

Hi, I would like to know if this is the right way to filter the results I get from service where I'm displaying only one result (like a detail).

I know I could use ng-repeat and filter it in the view and that is the cleanest, but I want to have more control over because I will re-use some of the data in the controller for other operations.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
$scope.savedEvents = Event.getPayedEvents(); //gets a list from service

//Goes through entire list and checks for a match   
angular.forEach($scope.savedEvents, function(event) {
    if (event.IdEvent == $stateParams.eventId) {
        $scope.showEvent = event;
    }
});
//now if there is a match I can use $scope.showEvent.eventName etc
```

Not sure if this would be easier using $filter to return just one event that has correct IdEvent. Or if someone has better solution, please let me know.

thanks

Comment: Not sure, but you may want to break out of the loop once you have set the variable. Should help a little, but what you have is fine.

Comment: Good point also! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with what you have, but you could inject the `$filter` service and do this one liner:

```
$scope.showEvent = $filter('filter')($scope.savedEvents, { IdEvent: $stateParams.eventId });
```

EDIT: Here is an easy way to resolve the result to a single value from the returned array:

```
var showEvents = $filter('filter')($scope.savedEvents, { IdEvent: $stateParams.eventId });
$scope.showEvent = showEvents && showEvents.length ? showEvents[0] : null;
```

In CoffeeScript it is a little more concise:

```
$scope.showEvent = $filter('filter')($scope.savedEvents, { IdEvent: $stateParams.eventId })?[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Ezekiel, this seems much 'cleaner', filter works as expected, how should I process $scope.showEvent because it returns array object so I cannot use it as $scope.showEvent.eventName. thanks

Comment: Oh of course, I went ahead and edited. CoffeeScript lets you keep that in one simple line using the existential operator `?`.

Comment: Awesome, so as I have a detail page that shows only one event I can just play safe and use $scope.showEvent = showEvents[0];